# How to execute current opened ruby file in IntelliJ?

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea

I'm quite new to IntelliJ and I'd like to use it like TextMate to execute ruby files.

When I hit `^R` I have to add file to the configuration, then I can execute it. How to tell IntelliJ to execute selected file (the one with focus) after I hit `^R`?

Intellij 10.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Run "<file>"` from the editor context menu (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> in the default keymap).